# How can I reset my Database in Laravel (PHP) via code

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Hello Everyone,**

I'm just trying to understand if I can reset my database as it was before a user session.

I've got a CRM system in `Laravel (PHP)` and I've created a demo version of the system which I'd be using to explain to my clients how the system works? and after every demo session, I want the database to reset back to previous data as before starting the user session.

I've got an SQL file and importing the same data in my new demo version. What I want is once the demo is given to the client, only the updated data should be cleared and only the records from the SQL file should remain as it is.

I really need to finish this as early as possible, please help me out with this.

Comment: `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` comes to mind

Comment: I've got an SQL file and importing the same data in my new demo version. 
What I want is once the demo is given to the client, only the updated data should be cleared and only the records from the SQL file should remain as it is

Comment: As said, Migrations along with Seeders seem appropriate for the job. Clears the database/tables and fills your app again with predefined data.